# svn locks and working copy directory issue

Tags: svn

I'm running into a problem where I'm unable to add my code onto svn properly. I try to say svn add  and it says that the parent folder is locked. However, when I say svn cleanup, it says the  that I had tried to add earlier isn't a working copy directory. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had mixed two svn working copy. 
try to fresh checkout from svn in new folder and add new content there.